# UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation: SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, ios, sigabrt, autorotate, crash-log

My app continues to crash on startup with this odd error: `-[UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23b5f0`.  The `_preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation` method is called for autorotation logic, so I took out all mentions of

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and cleaned the targets and build folder, but it kept logging the exception.  Has anyone encountered this strange error, and has anyone fixed it?

CRASH LOG:

```
2011-11-05 17:14:17.369 AppName[1542:707] -[UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23b5f0
2011-11-05 17:14:17.375 AppName[1542:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23b5f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x36da28bf 0x321121e5 0x36da5acb 0x36da4945 0x36cff680 0x31b35b7d 0x338532f9 0x33852e33 0x31b3be2d 0x3382cf19 0x36d01803 0x36d02491 0x31bee4bf 0x31befbb9 0x31b28a45 0x319b2227 0x319ac313 0x3197a921 0x3197a3bf 0x31979d2d 0x329d4e13 0x36d76553 0x36d764f5 0x36d75343 0x36cf84dd 0x36cf83a5 0x319ab457 0x319a8743 0x2cbb 0x2c60)
terminate called throwing an exceptionkill
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

EDIT 1:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //add the scroll view to our main window    
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [window addSubview:splashView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-67, -95, 492, 710);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:version forKey:@"version_preference"];

    return YES;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a line of coude like this in your appDelegate?

```
self.window.rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

This method `_preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation` is being called under the hood when transitions between UIViewControllers appear. The fact your `UIApplication` is the message receiver means you've casted it to be a view controller somewhere in your app or something like that.

Comment: Testing... it sounds correct.  I will post my current - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method

Comment: Beautiful, be sure to check out the splashView section of the source code.  It makes a really cool transition for the splash screen.